# Debezium connector over SSH tunnel getting Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, confluent-platform, ssh-tunnel, debezium

I am trying to wire Debezium source connector over SSH to a PostgreSQL database but I couldn't establish the connection. Getting this error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:6432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:190)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:788)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:783)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.determineDatabaseCharset(PostgresConnection.java:431)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Here is the connector configuration

```
"config":{
"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
"tasks.max":"1",
"database.hostname":"localhost",
"database.port":"6432",
"database.user":"test",
"database.password":"testpassword",
"database.dbname":"postgres",
"database.server.name":"localhost",
"transforms":"unwrap",
"transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
"transforms":"route",
"transforms.route.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.route.regex":"([^.]+).(^.]+).([^.]+)",
"transforms.route.replacement":"$3"
}
```

Although the connection to database through Database manager i.e Dbeaver or Pgdmin has been successful.

Comment: In order to connect through a tunnel, you need to have a tunnel.  Nothing you show here seems to be attempting to create one.

Comment: @jjanes the tunnel is available between the postgresql database VM and the VM where I am wiring the connector. That I couldn't show but the connection through the pgadmin has been successful.

Comment: So you are not using PgAdmin's built in tunnel capability, but are just pointing it to a pre-existing tunneled port?  If I need to debug something, I find psql far better than PgAdmin.  Anyway, the error message seems to show that the tunnel has failed, or is on a different port than you are trying.

Comment: @jjanes yes existing tunnel port. Pgadmin connection also established using the same tunneled port.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm facing the same situation without even the SSH in between. All docker images with ports exposed and connection working with dbBeaver